# spring-boot-maven-plugin created jar run by using classpath

Tags: java, maven-assembly-plugin, spring-boot-maven-plugin

used spring-boot-maven-plugin to build my jar, i'm to run it via

```
java -jar  myExample-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

but it throw error

> Error: Could not find or load main class com.manish.myexample.Example

while running via

```
java -cp  myExample-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.manish.myexample.Example
```

is because of spring-boot-maven-plugin ? and even tried

```
java -cp  libs/myExample-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar: BOOT-INF.classes.com.manish.myexample.Example
```

Answer (score 0):

You must ensure that you add the location of your .class file to your classpath. That is usually first mistake.

...and some general reasons why Java cannot find the class:

1. you made a mistake with the classname argument;
2. the application's classpath is incorrectly specified: the wrong directory is on the classpath, the subdirectory path doesn't match or dependencies missing from the classpath;
3. the class has been declared in the wrong package.

Comment: have checked all except setting class-path , maven-assembly-plugin and spring-boot-maven-plugin have different policies for building jar file